# Render Zend\Form\Element\Button with content and without label

Tags: php, button, zend-form, zend-framework2

It seems like it's impossible to render a button element automatically using the `FormCollection` view helper without label.

Whenever possible, I render forms this way:

```
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($this->form); ?>
    <?php echo $this->formCollection($this->form); ?>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag($this->form); ?>
```

However, the `FormButton` view helper, that is invoked by `FormCollection`, awaits the button's content as second param to the `render()` method -- or a label option. If I set the label, the button renders correctly, but, you guess it, with label.

I tried to figure out a workaround for this by browsing through the code, but I can't see one.

**Note:** FormButton renders `<button>...</button>` elements. I could also live with a `<input type="button" />` element.

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own formCollection ViewHelper that uses your very own formButton ViewHelper.

Comment: Yes, this is the most obvious solution, however, I wonder if there is a native way.

Answer (score 2):

When I was struggling with this problem, I've got the solution accidentally! It is so easy (or hackish?), that I wouldn't have thought to work.

Add this to your fieldset:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'delete',
    'attributes' => array('type'=>'button', 'value' => 'Delete', 'onclick'=>'delete()'),
));
```

That's all. It is working for me very well.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Quick and easy. Thank you!